# What is the net current through this LR circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, inductor, alternator

Here is the problem which I was asked to do.[image: THis is the problem]

I started by the method of phasors considering first the upper branch of the circuit Drawing phasors as follows :

[image]

Then for the lower circuit i drew the phasors along the main voltage line shown below the red line in above image.As it was purely resistive so phasors of current and voltage(of 100 ohm resistance) will be in phase. then I calculated the magnitude of each current phasor I1 and I2 and added them vectorially as follows[image]

But when i submitted it the ans came out to be x=2.05.Can someone guide me on this?? thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Your answer is right!

Well, using complex analysis we can see that:

$$\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{in}}=\frac{\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}}{\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}}\tag1$$

Now, when working with sinusoidal voltages we know that we can write:

$$\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}=\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}\exp\left(\varphi\text{j}\right)\tag2$$

So, we can write for the maximum:

$$\left|\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{in}}\right|=\left|\frac{\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}}{\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}}\right|=\frac{\left|\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}\right|}{\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\right|}=\frac{\left|\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}\exp\left(\varphi\text{j}\right)\right|}{\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\right|}=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}}{\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\right|}\tag3$$

Looking at your circuit, we can see that:

$$\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}=\text{R}_1\space\text{||}\space\left(\text{R}_2+\text{j}\text{X}_\text{L}\right)=\frac{\text{R}_1\cdot\left(\text{R}_2+\text{j}\text{X}_\text{L}\right)}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{j}\text{X}_\text{L}}\tag4$$

Taking the absolute value gives:

$$\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\right|=\frac{\text{R}_1\sqrt{\text{R}_2^2+\text{X}_\text{L}^2}}{\sqrt{\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)^2+\text{X}_\text{L}^2}}\tag5$$

So, we end up with:

$$\left|\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{in}}\right|=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)^2+\text{X}_\text{L}^2}}{\sqrt{\text{R}_2^2+\text{X}_\text{L}^2}}\tag6$$

---

So, in order to solve your question we need to solve:

$$\frac{\sqrt{100x}}{5}=\frac{100}{100}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{\left(100+30\right)^2+40^2}}{\sqrt{30^2+40^2}}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x=\frac{37}{20}=1.85\tag7$$